# Make Sidebar Fill Availible Vertical Space

Tags: css, html, space

http://www.akebulan.org/index.html

I am trying to get the sidebar to take up the space it has available. If I set both html and body to 100% the div becomes much larger than needed. I want it to match the container on the right. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: By sidebar I am referring to the div marked with the header "Who are we?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want set background on 100% height left side:

1. set background in div id="main-div" like this background: url('img/Texture2.jpg');
2. set background in div class="col-lg-8" like this: style="background: #f7f7f7;";

your example: [travelletters.ru/test.html](http://travelletters.ru/test.html)

Comment: Nah cause it has to repeat on the x axis as well... change the aspect ratio to a smaller size and you'll see why.

Comment: ok. set  div id="main-div" background: url('img/Texture2.jpg'); and set  background: #f7f7f7; in div class="col-lg-8" like this: style="background: #f7f7f7;"

Comment: Good Fix Bro... kinda hacky but I like it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your content is bigger than your sidebar.

What you could do is have a 'main-content' div (which contains your sidebar), and you just set your sidebar to `height=100%`, so it fills the vertical space needed by taking into account the content on the right

Comment: The sidebar is not inside the main content. The container which hold the sidebar and the news area has it's height set to 100%.

Comment: @JTNolan Yup, that's what you could do though, make a container-div that holds the main-content AND the sidebar so that when you set the sidebar to height 100%, it takes into account the main-content.

Comment: That didn't work. It is pushed to production so you can view my change on the site given in the question.

Comment: @JTNolan No offense, but you must be doing something wrong, I just did it through chrome's inspector and the sidebar was filled until the footer. That's what you're trying to do right?

Comment: For some reason when I make a div surrounding the two pieces of content it is the width of the browser and 0px tall. It floats to the top. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Your sidebar is overiding your content, so there needs to be some buffer or add height css